# Apache Spark concatenate several rows into a list in one row

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to create a table(hive table/spark dataframe) from a source table that stores data of users in `N` rows into a list in one row.

```
User table:
Schema:  userid: string | transactiondate:string | charges: string
----|------------|-------| 
123 | 2017-09-01 | 20.00 | 
124 | 2017-09-01 | 30.00 | 
125 | 2017-09-01 | 20.00 | 
126 | 2017-09-01 | 30.00 | 
456 | 2017-09-01 | 20.00 | 
457 | 2017-09-01 | 30.00 | 
458 | 2017-09-01 | 20.00 | 
459 | 2017-09-01 | 30.00 |
```

Output table should be

```
User table:
Schema:  userid: string | transactiondate:string | charges: string 
------------------|-----------------------------------------------|-------------------------
[123,124,125,126] | [2017-09-01,2017-09-01,2017-09-01,2017-09-01] | [20.00,30.00,20.00,30.00]
[456,457,458,459] | [2017-09-01,2017-09-01,2017-09-01,2017-09-01] | [20.00,30.00,20.00,30.00]
```

Comment: What the criteria for grouping? How to determine what group row should belong to?

Comment: we will assign a parameter `N`, so we gather `N` items in order or random into a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a key value to group the data. I made an `id` column and `groupBy` this column.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val N = 4
val agg_list = df.columns.map(c => collect_list(c).as(c))
val w = Window.orderBy("transactiondate", "userid")

df.withColumn("id", ((row_number.over(w) - 1) / N).cast("int"))
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(agg_list.head, agg_list.tail: _*)
  .drop("id").show(false)
```

The result is:

```
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
|userid              |transactiondate                                                                     |charges                 |
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
|[123, 124, 125, 126]|[2017-09-01 00:00:00, 2017-09-01 00:00:00, 2017-09-01 00:00:00, 2017-09-01 00:00:00]|[20.0, 30.0, 20.0, 30.0]|
|[456, 457, 458, 459]|[2017-09-01 00:00:00, 2017-09-01 00:00:00, 2017-09-01 00:00:00, 2017-09-01 00:00:00]|[20.0, 30.0, 20.0, 30.0]|
+--------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------+
```